# Notation Confusion Reading Nick Katz' Proof of RH for (Projective, Smooth, Geometrically Connected) Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Trying to read this so-called "Note" by Nick Katz and cannot get over some of his notation. The fundamental group stuff is fine, but then he...seems to define some notation with the same notation in the definition in the first paragraph of page 2. Letting $U_0/\mathbb{F}_q$ be an affine, smooth, geommetrically connected curve, we let

$R^i:= R^if_\star\mathbb{Q}_\ell$

for every morphism $f:\chi\rightarrow U_0$. I'm *guessing* that the $f_\star$ is the same as $f_*$, a pushforward by $f$ of $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ to the $i$th cohomology group of $U_0$, but I don't know what this $R^i$ is supposed to be when it's defined by itself...

Anyone care to clarify and help me understand what Nick Katz might be meaning by $R^i$?

(Here's a copy of the note itself: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/baby16.pdf )

Comment: Maybe the (right) [derived functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor).

Comment: @Quasicoherent After some reading, I see that you're right! Thanks for sending me down the right path without overloading me with the definitions and such themselves. (I have my own resources--like FoAG--to use for looking up such definitions when I know what I'm looking for haha.) Do you think that the $f_{\star}$ means the pushforward of $\ell$-adic cohomology?